# "Because of" vs. "due to" — best choice to explain a reason?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Given the sentence,

> This exception was thrown *_*_ invalid input.

Which preposition should I use to fill in the blank — *because of* or *due to*?

Is either generally preferable for specifying cause or reason?

Comment: The query is hard (for me) to answer because I don’t recognise the idiom _to throw an exception_.  What is it meant to mean?

Comment: @Daniel Harbour see at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simply, *due to* modifies nouns and *because of* modifies verbs. They are not interchangeable, though the perception of *due to* being 'more intelligent' than *because of* ensures that plenty of people misuse it - delicious irony!

Example:

> His failure was due to poor preparation

Here, *due to poor preparation* is modifying *his failure* via the linking verb *was*, so the sentence works. If we change the sentence:

> He failed due to poor preparation

Here, *due to poor preparation* is modifying.... errrrr. There is nothing for it to modify. If we correct the sentence:

> He failed because of poor preparation

Now, *because of* modifies *failed* and the sentence works.

You will hear some people saying this is prescriptive and old fashioned blah blah blah, but they are simple excusing ignorance by calling it language change. Not knowing an adjective from and adverb is not language change.

Looking at my examples, notice how *due to* follows *was*, and *because of* doesn't? That is one quick and easy indicator that you should be using *due to*. Another is to substitute *caused by*.

> His failure was caused by poor preparation

is okay, but

> *He failed caused by poor preparation

isn't.

Using your example, substituting *caused by* gives us

> This exception was thrown caused by invalid input.

which doesn't work, nor is there a linking verb, so

> This exception was thrown because of invalid input.

Further reading can be found in:

- The [BBC Style Guide](http://www2.media.uoa.gr/lectures/linguistic_archives/academic_papers0506/notes/stylesheets_3.pdf) - "Due to. This means caused by, not because of".
- The [Telegraph Style Guide](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/topics/about-us/style-book/1435310/Telegraph-style-book-Dd.html) - "due to is used adjectivally and, therefore, needs a noun to modify"
- The [Economist Style Guide](http://www.economist.com/styleguide/d#node-21533334) - "When used to mean caused by, due to must follow a noun, as in The cancellation, due to rain, of... Do not write It was cancelled due to rain. If you mean because of and for some reason are reluctant to say it, you probably want owing to. It was cancelled owing to rain is all right."
- [Elements of Style](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk3.html) - "Due to. Incorrectly used for through, because of, or owing to, in adverbial phrases: "He lost the first game, due to carelessness." In correct use related as predicate or as modifier to a particular noun: "This invention is due to Edison;" "losses due to preventable fires.""
- [Kansas University](http://web.ku.edu/~edit/because.html) - " The word pairs “because of” and “due to” are not interchangeable. The reason they are not is that they “grew up” differently in the language. 
   “Because of” grew up as an adverb; “due to” grew up as an adjective. Remember that adjectives modify only nouns or pronouns, whereas adverbs usually modify verbs."

Comment: Great! I suspected as much. Can you suggest some related "further reading"?

Comment: @RoaringFish Well explained.Thanks for your answer,that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, you can't escape the fact that such a rule *is* prescriptive! When you suggest that the reason people don't apply the rule is because of not being able to distinguish one part of speech from another, do you actually have evidence for this assertion? When you imply that this rule historically reflected usage, do you have evidence for this? I would posit that it doesn't really matter whether a rule is 'old-fashioned': the question is more whether or not it is actually adopted by respected writers and/or whether it serves a useful purpose. (In both cases, you may find the answer is 'no'...)

Comment: N.B. In any case, it's not clear that all prescriptivists advocate such a rule. For example, Fowler's main concern appears to have between 'due to' and 'owing to'-- he for one doesn't really make a song and dance about 'because of' as far as I can see.

Comment: @AviralSingh ~ a few 'further reading' links to style guides etc. added.

Comment: And a comment typical of those Roaring Fish has avoided: (at http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~jlynch/Writing/d.html ) 'Some folks object to the phrase _due to_ when it's used prepositionally: “He stayed home due to the flu.” I don't much like it myself — I find it inelegant, and avoid it in my own speech and writing — but it's so widespread that there's little point campaigning against it anymore.' I concur.

Comment: I asked you earlier to explain why an adverb/adjective distinction is prescriptive, but following other prescriptive rules isn't. Your response was "weight of advice given in style guides" but you fail to produce a single one that supports your position. Now you can come up with a blog - a blog that agrees with my post that 'due to' is an adjective! I already know that a lot of people don't know how to use 'due to' and 'because of' - "You will hear some people saying this is prescriptive and old fashioned blah blah blah, but they are simple excusing ignorance by calling it language change."

Comment: Due to, owing to and because of - Due to and owing to mean ‘because of’ and are therefore interchangeable. All three are prepositions. While all three are acceptable, ‘due to’ is more commonly used. (32 Trialogue Style Guide, April 2012) Also, the BAEF group referred to below state that fighting this trend is like trying to turn back the tide. I'm not saying I like the development - but English is always changing (from a form necessarily considered 'purer' by many of the old school). One always has to bear in mind that the grammar they defend was probably once considered outrageous by some.

Answer (score 1):

Roaring Fish's answer is prescriptivist, and apparently uses only 'selective' (ie not looking at the **whole** history) prescriptivism.

At http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/give+someone+her+due is found:

> Idioms
>
> 11.
>   **due to**
>
> a. attributable to; ascribable to [I'll add 'caused by']: The delay was due to heavy traffic.
>
> b. because of; owing to: All planes are grounded due to fog.
>
> ...
>
> **Usage note**
>
> 1. Due to  as a prepositional phrase meaning “because of, owing to” has been in use since the 14th century: Due to the sudden rainstorm,
>      the picnic was moved indoors.  Some object to this use on the grounds
>      that due is historically an adjective and thus should be used only
>      predicatively in constructions like The delay was due to electrical
>      failure.

And from the related thread here (I've reformatted slightly):

> Fowler's Modern English Usage points out that the objection to “due
>   to” as a compound preposition “is an entirely 20th Century phenomenon - but it
>   begins to look as if this use of ‘due to’ *will* form part of the
>   natural language of the 21st Century” .
>
> The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style agrees,
>   stating that “The tide has turned toward accepting ‘due to’ as a
>   full-fledged preposition.” - See more at:
>   http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-due-to-since-and-as?page=all#sthash.ud7a2XSe.dpuf

(I'd prefer 'and what is more' to the 'but' in the quote from *Fowler*.)

Comment: N.B. The prescriptive issue with 'due to' here is essentially to do with its use vs 'owing to', not 'because of'. You mention Fowler, but as far as I can see it's not clear that he had an objection to 'because of' in either usage.

Comment: The original Fowler argument is more syntax-orientated: The argument against using due to as a compound preposition is that 'due' is a predicative adjective: Then pay to Caesar what is due to Caesar...(NEB) The train is due (to arrive) at 10.56. and as such cannot stand alone to introduce a clause: The cancellation of the barbecue was due to rain. is acceptable but Due to rain the barbecue was cancelled. should be Owing to rain the barbecue was cancelled.( http://lavengro.typepad.com/peter_harvey_linguist/2013/05/english-and-the-guardian.html)If the com prep is OK, it can replace 'because of'.

Comment: I'm perfectly familiar with Fowler's original argument (though it's actually nonsense, of course: there's really no line of logic that precludes a compound preposition based on a predicative adjective [or anything else] from being used to introduce an absolute adverbial to a clause-- that's just something languages do...). But my point is simply that Fowler doesn't actually mention 'because of' and doesn't directly make a comparison between 'due/owing to' and 'because of'; his observations are about the choice between 'due to' and 'owing to'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ~ you are happy enough to follow prescriptive rules about capital letters, full stops, verb tenses, parenthesis etc. in your post. Can you justify why those prescriptive rules are good but *due to* being an adjective is bad? Nor do I see anything in your quotes that says it isn't, or in fact anything that contradicts anything I said.

Comment: @Roaring Fish : Weight of advice given in style guides. I don't think you'll find any recommendation to change from the style you say I use ('capital letters, full stops, verb tenses, parenthesis etc.') - but there _are_ style guides licensing the _growing usage_ of 'due to' as a compound preposition. In my view, this makes it a _descriptive_ argument you're opposing here.

Comment: "The weight of advice"? Really? Provide some links then. I would like to see all these style guides that you claim are advising that due to and because are interchangeable. The BBC contradicts you ('Due to.This means caused by, not because of'), so does the Economist ('If you mean because of and for some reason are reluctant to say it, you probably want owing to'), the Telegraph ('due to is used adjectivally and, therefore, needs a noun to modify') and the Guardian mentions a dispute with *owing to* but not *because of*.

Comment: Did you miss the references I gave? I'm arguing against your dogmatic 'Very simply, _due to_ modifies nouns and _because of_ modifies verbs. They are not interchangeable'. The Guardian SG has: 'due to or owing to?
Traditionalists argue that ... "due to" should only be used when it is the complement of the verb "to be"; otherwise, use "owing to" or "because of": ... The distinction, once routinely taught in primary schools but now assailed on all sides ... is being lost.'  Ie 'due to' _is_ often being used instead of 'owing to' where it matches, and in place of 'because of' where it matches.

Comment: AHD has a usage note allowing the usage of 'due to' as a compound preposition at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/due+to . University of Hull linguists state 'The two phrases 'due to' and 'owing to' seem to be used interchangeably in everyday English, but there is a pedantic dislike of using 'due to' in the same way as 'owing to' among some academics. Like many pedantic dislikes, this one flourishes in academic circles - and appears to have little real reason behind it.' at http://slb-ltsu.hull.ac.uk/awe/index.php?title=Due_to_-_owing_to .

Comment: At http://www.editorsforum.org/forum_index_articles/editing_05-16-02.php one finds: "These are ten items that I find to be big headaches simply because people disagree about them or still have old rules and superstitions about them," she said. "I find these are things that I waste a lot of time on. I change my mind from month to month."

Of the ten, the BAEF audience were in agreement on only a few—that it's sometimes OK to split infinitives; that "data" is sometimes singular; and that "due to" can be used as a compound preposition like "because of" or "owing to."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ~ have you read my post? Have you noticed how 'owing to' doesn't appear anywhere in it? You are barking up the wrong tree; attacking a straw man. I have said nothing about 'owing to' -v- 'due to', and you have found nothing that contradicts what I did say - that 'due to' modifies nouns and 'because of' modifies verbs.